# How to configure Tomcat to serve at port 80 on root path?

Tags: tomcat

I have an application running on a Tomcat server at `http://example.com:8080/webapp`.

I would like my app to be accessible at `http://example.com`.

How to remove the `:8080/webapp` path?

Comment: You can either use an apache server as a gateway proxy or configure tomcat via its `server.xml` configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To change the port, edit the connector element in `serverl.xml`. Such as in:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

For deploying at the root, you can change the path in the context element such as in:

```
<Context path="" docBase="war_name" debug="0" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

Here is a question about setting the context path to root:

- [Deploying my application at the root in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328518/deploying-my-application-at-the-root-in-tomcat)

An interesting article about tomcat configuration:

- [Tomcat server.xml Configuration Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/tomcat/tomcat-server-xml-configuration-example/)

For details, read the tomcat documentation:

- [Connector element](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)
- [Context element](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html)